# Maven exits bash run when profile is set, and build fails

Tags: bash, maven, sh

I'm writing a deployment script, and I have to know if an operation was failed. I use the following approach:

```
run_command
COMMAND_RESULT=$?
if [[ "$COMMAND_RESULT" -ne 0 ]] ; then
    do_something
    exit 1
fi
```

It works when:

```
mvn -T 16 clean install
BUILD_RESULT=$?
if [[ "$BUILD_RESULT" -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Build failed."
  exit 1
fi
```

And:

```
./infra/deployment/script/wait_for_pods_ready.sh $NAMESPACE_NAME 30 5
STARTUP_RESULT=$?
if  [[ "$STARTUP_RESULT" -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo "Services failed to start."
  kubectl delete namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME
  exit 1;
fi
```

And:

```
mvn -T 16 clean test
TEST_RESULT=$?
if  [[ "$TEST_RESULT" -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo "Tests failed"
  kubectl delete namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME
  exit 1;
else
  echo "Tests passed successfully"
fi
```

But as soon as I set the maven profile:

```
mvn -T 16 clean test -P integration
TEST_RESULT=$?
if  [[ "$TEST_RESULT" -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo "Tests failed"
  kubectl delete namespace $NAMESPACE_NAME
  exit 1;
else
  echo "Tests passed successfully"
fi
```

The script exits when the maven build fails, without writing "Tests failed" and deleting the namespace.

It seems like maven stops the whole bash script when the build fails, and a maven profile is set.
If the profile is not set, or the build is successful, then the script writes the success message, and goes on properly.

Do I do something wrong, or it is a bug in maven?

Comment: First I see `-T 16 ` really needed? How many modules do you have? Furthermore what does `integration` profile controle?

Comment: I have 2 profiles: Default is `service`, what is responsible for service build. `integration` is responsible for integration tests (BE and Selenium)
Parallel build is necessary for service build, because Docker build and push is added to the mvn install phase, and it causes some idle time what can be reduced with parallelism.

Comment: So you are using maven-failsafe-plugin for running integration tests via naming convention like `*IT.java` ?  If you have only two modules `-T 16` does not makes sense. Furthermore do you make the docker build via Maven? So you have integration tests running in your integration profile...Do the run fine? Do you use  `maven-failsafe-plugin:verify`? Have tried to run on plain command line `mvn clean install -Pintegration` what is the result?

Comment: No, I run mvn commands twice. My deployment steps: 1. run `mvn clean install` to build the jars, create docker images and push them to DockerHub. 2. create and setup kubernetes namespace, and deploy the services 3. wait for the services to start 4. run `mvn clean test -Pintegration` to run tests against the application deployed to Kubernetes. (you can see the deployment script here: https://github.com/Saphyra/apphub/blob/2808da47566eb4bcfbe0bf3f3b36a336db13e90f/deploy_all.sh) Everything works fine except the test namespace is not deleted when the integration test fails.